# PDO not inserting into DB

Tags: php, jquery, pdo, http-post

Failing to see why the data isn't being inserted...  I have jQuery, HTML, and PHP code that will all be posted below.  Tried debugging to no avail.  Thanks.

PHP Code:

```
<?php
include_once('db.php');
session_start();

    $message = $_POST['message'];

        if($message < 100 && $message > 2) {

            $insertMessage = $db->prepare("INSERT INTO `chats`(`time`, `message`, `username`) VALUES(:time, :message, :username)");

                $insertMessage->execute(array(

                        ':time'     => date("g:i a"),
                        ':message'  => $message,
                        ':username' => $_SESSION['username']

                    ));


        }
?>
```

jQuery Code:

```
$("#chatBtn").click( function() {
 $.post( $(".chatForm").attr("action"), 
         $(".chatForm :input").serializeArray(), 
         function(info){ $("#chatResult").html(info); 
      $('#message').val('');

   });
});

$(".chatForm").submit( function() {
  return false; 
  $('#message').val('');
});
```

HTML Code:

```
<form action="./php/send_chat.php" method="POST" class="chatForm">
<p class="field">
<input type="text" id="message" name="message" style="width: 275px;">
<span><button type="submit" id="chatBtn">Send</button>
</p>
</form>
```

Comment: What debugging have you tried?

Comment: It seems like it's not communicating with the file whatsoever...

I tried echoing out something and it's not showing in HTML.

Comment: Nope, no errors.  Just not inserting into the DB.

Answer (score -2):

First simplify your insert using hardcoded parameters and in a try/catch with [exceptions](http://www.php.net/manual/en/pdo.error-handling.php)
PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION fires an exception, allows you to handle errors gracefully. 
Once this produces the required result incrementally modify your code checking after each modification . This is Basic debugging.

```
<?php
include_once("db.php");
$message ="Test Message";
$username = "username";
// connect to the database  
try {  
    $db = new PDO("mysql:host=$host;dbname=$database", $username, $password);  
    $db->setAttribute( PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION );  
    //
    $insertMessage = $db->prepare("INSERT INTO `chats`(`time`, `message`, `username`) VALUES(:time, :message, :username)");
    $insertMessage->execute(array(
        ':time'     => date("g:i a"),
        ':message'  => $message,
        ':username' => $username
        ));

  }   
catch(PDOException $e) {  
    echo "I'm sorry I'm afraid you can't do that.". $e->getMessage() ;// Remove or modify after testing 
}  

?>
```

Comment: why "Remove or modify after testing"? Why not to let it go without catch **already?**